# Mean of a function of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

I have three random variables ($A$, $B$, $C$). The mean of these variables are $12$, $5.6$, $0.2$ respectively. The standard deviations are $0.4$, $0.8$, $0.2$ respectively. The probability density function of each variable is normal (gaussian). The correlation coefficient is $0.5$ for each couples of variables. I would to calculate the mean of the random variable

$Z = e^{ABC}$

but I have no idea how to do that.

Furthermore, the exercise tell me to calculate the mean of $Z$ in the case $A$, $B$, $C$ are uniform (rectangular) with half-width $0.4$, $0.8$, $0.2$ respectively. This time, the correlation coefficient is $1$ for each couples of variables.

Unfortunately, my degree doesn't have a course in probability, so it could be a big help for me if you would explain me the intermediate steps.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not possible to solve the problem unless a joint distribution between $A,B,C$ is known.  For example, if we knew $A,B,C$ were mutually independent, we could proceed.  In general it seems you are being asked to compute $E[h(A,B,C)]$, where $h$ is a function, and the formula for that is $$E[h(A,B,C)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(a,b,c) f_{A,B,C}(a,b,c)da \: db \: dc$$ which of course requires a joint PDF $f_{A,B,C}(a,b,c)$. Plug in the specific function $h$, plug in the specific joint PDF, and you are done (with an answer in integral form).

Comment: Hi, I forgot to tell you that in the first exercise the correlation coefficient of each couples of variables is $r = 0.5$, while in the latter is $r = 1$.

Comment: What is the context of this problem? Where are these "exercises" coming from?  Note that stating the correlation coefficients suffices to specify the joint PDF of $(A,B,C)$ in the first exercise only in the special case when $(A,B,C)$ are "jointly Gaussian."   Stating the correlation coefficients in the second exercise does not help to specify the joint PDF. Also, I do not know what "half-width" means. To specify the marginal PDF of a uniform random variable $X$, you would need to specify the interval $[a,b]$ over which it is uniform.

Comment: Hi, you can consider $A$, $B$, $C$ as three parameters obtained by direct measurements, and the variable $Z$ as an indirect measurement (that is, $Z$ defines an equation of measurement). Sorry, in the second exercise, $A$ is uniform over $[−0.4;0.4]$, $B$ is uniform over $[−0.8;0.8]$ and $C$ is uniform over $[−0.2;0.2]$. Both exercises also ask to evaluate the "combined uncertainty" of $Z$, and I have no problem do to that (so this is a reason why the exercise gives me the correlation coefficients).

Comment: You have not stated where these exercises are from and you have not provided any information that establishes the joint PDF of $(A,B,C)$.

Comment: @Michael These exercises come from a collection of Electrical Measurement's exam tests provided by my Professor. He provides only the information above. However, how can I proceed if $(A,B,C)$ are jointly Gaussian ?

Comment: The jointly Gaussian case you already have an answer for in the above comments ("Plug in the specific function $h$, plug in the specific joint PDF, and you are done").   You can ask your professor what is intended for the second exercise, since providing only covariance information does not generally specify a joint PDF. If $A,B,C$ were assumed to be mutually independent then the joint PDF is just the product of marginals.

Comment: @Michael Thanks a lot! I will ask him what you told me about.